# PHP/SQL - PHP won't output sql query

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

could you please help me? just trying to fill in some text as stackoverflow wants to write more text because it's all code

Comment: `$row["f.roundID"]` ---> `$row["roundID"]`, I believe.

Comment: @Enstage i've tried that but still doesn't generate any roundID (INT)

Comment: and what do you expect the result would be?

Comment: any chance of a screenshot of the expect result rather than in words cheers

Comment: sorry im really bad at this, how do i upload a screenshot onto stack?

Comment: can you please post your first page and expected output page. i don't really understand what you want to see and do. cheers

Comment: how do i upload a screenshot?

Comment: hey @maSTAShuFu i have uploaded.

Comment: just updated my answer

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that is not working as intended.

Comment: your questionis not clear

Answer (score 0):

alias on this field

```
SELECT f.roundID as froundID
```

then use single quotes not double

```
$row['froundID']
```

AND THE BIGGER PROBLEM IS THE SQL QUERY

```
FROM fixtures AS f
INNER JOIN team AS h
  ON f.homeTeam = h.teamID
  AND f.awayTeam = h.teamID
```

which will not return anything because the awayteam and hometeam should be the same in a row...

to correct should be OR where it can be either the hometeam or awayteam

```
FROM fixtures AS f
INNER JOIN team AS h
  ON (f.homeTeam = h.teamID
  OR f.awayTeam = h.teamID)
```

with the updated requirement you need to create 3 queries 

 where 

 1 - get the rounds

 2 - get the teams

 3 - get the venue

Comment: if i change $sql to something more basic, it outputs the roundID's

Comment: $row['froundID'] --- it should be over single quote

Comment: i've made it single quotation but still no output

Comment: if you just put an HTML text inside the loop will this display?

Comment: so i added a <p> hi </p> and nothing is being displayed. so my best bet is that the while loop aint working.

Comment: if i change the sql to a really simple one for eg, SELECT roundID from round; the while loop prints all the rounds. however if i have this long $sql statement, the while loop doesnt execute...

Comment: and if you execute your long sql statement over the workbench or studio will it give you anything?

Comment: found your issue @DerickLarson... see my updated answer

Comment: i dont have access to those tools

Comment: omg now it's working but it's causing another issue. it only populates the integer of which the value of session variable is being passed.  for eg

if i have a session variable = 5
the round dropdown list only populates 5, 16 times( don't know why it only generates 16 times)

Comment: probably because there are about 16 5 round games in your table. probably you want to narrow down your query.

Comment: how do i further narrow it down? 

the dropdown list should only be 1 - 26 as opposed to 5, 16times...

Comment: okay first and foremost what do you want to do? you have a team table a ground table and fixtures table

Comment: hey so i updated my code.

on a different php page, a user inputs a round ranging between 1 - 26. I created a session variable which stores that round number and it sends it to the code above. 

in this code i want to display 3 different info via dropdown list.
these are 
1. rounds 1 - 26 (currently only displaying session variable x 16times)
2. all the teams competing, and 
3. integer of all venues.

Comment: if i remove = AND f.roundID = $retrieveRound, 
the session variable is removed from the sql statement
which takes me back to my original issue.

now Round displays 1 - 26 but it is being displayed 8 times per digit.
for eg, 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 etc.

how do i make it so it only displays 1 2 3 4 etc.?

Comment: are you only after of display round #s with no descriptions?

Comment: yes no descriptions

the rounds should ONLY display 1 - 26.
likewise the team heading should only display ALL team names
and venue should only produce all venues in integers

Answer (score 0):

Your query is like:

`select a.column, b.columnz from table a inner join table b on a.key = b.key`

So when you get the result like:

```
column   columnz
xxxxx    yyyyyy
```

So your PHP

`<?php echo $row["f.roundID"]?>"><?php echo $row["f.roundID"]?>`

should be in this way:

`<?php echo $row["roundID"]?>"><?php echo $row["roundID"]?>`

Comment: hey so i've already tried your statement but it still displays nothing...

Comment: have you tested your query on your mysql database workbench?

Comment: then download it into your workstation, access it by using database name, ip address, username, password that you have.