# calling sql alias in PHP

Tags: php, sql

Can someone please point where i am going wrong here, i keep receiving an error in my sql statement. I have had to use an alias because i am trying to display the names of two football teams in a fixture list. my sql looks like this so far:

```
$sql = "SELECT homeTeam, awayTeam, roundID, teamID, teamName, logo, groundName, away.abbreviatedName AS abbreviatedNameAway, home.abbreviatedName AS abbreviatedNameHome, matchDate, matchTime, venue FROM fixtures 
      INNER JOIN team home ON fixtures.homeTeam = home.teamID 
      INNER JOIN team away ON fixtures.awayTeam = away.teamID 
      INNER JOIN ground ON ground.groundID = home.groundID";
```

and my PHP code to echo this out is like this:

```
    <td><?php echo $row ["home.abbreviatedName"]?></td>
    <td> V  </td>
    <td><?php echo $row ["away.abbreviatedName"] ?></td>
```

the tables which i am using are:

```
team           | fixtures   | ground
------         | ------     | groundID
teamID         | matchID    | groundName
abbreviatedname| homeTeam   |
groundID       | awayTeam   |
               | venue
```

where homeTeam & awayTeam are essentially teamID's and venue is groundID
The error i receive is:

```
Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given
```

Comment: What error? The exact error is often very informative and specific, and also hard to determine from your example code.

Comment: i have edited the post to show the error i am getting

Comment: wonder if this is a case of the entire sql or php construct is wrong similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44014297/php-sql-php-wont-output-sql-query/44014348?noredirect=1#comment75057714_44014348

Comment: that turned out to be an assignment

Comment: You'll need to edit again and add the code that generates that error. It's also useful to add the code where you actually run that query.

Answer (score 0):

away.abbreviatedName AS abbreviatedNameAway 
home.abbreviatedName abbreviatedNameHome

should be

```
$row ["abbreviatedNameAway"] 
$row ["abbreviatedNameHome"]
```